# How to count occurrences when the gap between the values is greater than x

Tags: mysql, sum, gaps-and-islands

Considering a simple MySQL table with a id column and a int column, I need to count how many times I have a **gap** equal or greater than certain value.

Let's say that value will be 10.

Given the following sample records:

```
{1, 2, 3} = 1 time
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} = 1 time;
{1, 2, 3, 14, 17} = 2 times (1, 2, 3 and 14, 17);
{1, 2, 3, 14, 20, 40, 42} = 3 times (1, 2, 3 and 14, 20 and 40, 42);
```

Is it possible resolve that with mysql?

Comment: Search for `gaps and islands`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For table `t` with columns `id` and `num` this will be seems like this:

```
SET @n = 10;

SELECT 1 + SUM(COALESCE(t3.f, 0))
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.num, (
        SELECT CASE WHEN t2.num - t1.num > @n THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM t t2 
        WHERE t2.num > t1.num 
        ORDER BY num LIMIT 1
    ) AS f
    FROM t t1
) t3
```